Conditionally defining a class variable
Is the following code considered Pythonic?
class A():
    if True:
        x = 10

print(A.x) # prints 10

This came to my mind when working on a plugin based application.

Personally I would prefer the member always exist, and in some cases be None.

I would say no to being Pythonic. "Explicit is better than implicit.".

There's no issue with the code you've posted. Many times before, I've written logic within a class definition.
I do suggest per @Cory's comments to define it as None or a different number if False, so the attribute will always be defined.
